# Clashing Libraries in Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7

How do I fix clashing libraries in Tomcat 7?

I need to use these two classes:

```
javax.servlet.Servlet
javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo
```

Servlet is included in servlet-api.jar, which is provided by Tomcat 7, in its own lib directory.

UriInfo is provided by javaee-web-api-6.0.jar. But that library also includes Servlet.class! So if I include that 2nd library, I get this error:

```
INFO: validateJarFile(/Users/.../web/WEB-INF/lib/javaee-web-api-6.0.jar) - jar not
loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. 
Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

But if I don't include it, I get this error:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo
```

And I can't just replace servlet-api.jar in the Tomcat distribution with javaee-web-api-6.0.jar, because it's not a superset. Neither file is a super set of the other, but they have a lot in common.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

(P.S. I don't use Maven, so I can't just ask it to fix things for me.)

Comment: What happens to the application if you include the jar? Does it still work properly?